# If statement in Excel to recognize a leap year

Tags: excel-2003

How could I write a If statement in Excel to divide a cell by 2088 if it is a leap year, and if it is not a leap year divide the same cell by 2080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put this in A2:

```
=IF(OR(MOD(A1,400)=0,AND(MOD(A1,4)=0,MOD(A1,100)<>0)),2088, 2080)
```

And then put the year you care about in A1 and your value in B1 and then do:

```
=B1/A2
```

See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214019) Technet article for further info (I used the IF statement from there as a base).

Edit: Or do you mean that you want to divide the year by that value? If so add the following in any cell but A1:

```
=IF(OR(MOD(A1,400)=0,AND(MOD(A1,4)=0,MOD(A1,100)<>0)), A1 / 2088, A1 / 2080)
```

And put the year in A1.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain to me what that if statment is doing?

Comment: @Edmon: The rules are, if you can divide the year by 400 or if you can divide it by 4 but not by 100, then it's a leap year. The code uses Excel's `OR` and `AND` functions to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

In GREGORIAN CALENDAR most years which are multiple of 4 are leap years.
But three leap years are omitted every 400 years.
So in order to be a leap year, the year should be divisible by 4 except the centennial years, which are not divisible by 400.
for eg. 2000 was a leap year but 2100,2200 and 2300 will not be.

And to be more precise check this link
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214019